# Android ActionBar with AdMob

Tags: android, android-actionbar, admob

I have created the application with ActionBar and ActionBar tabs. I wish to add advertisements in my application like AdMob, in Actionbar top and bottom. How to do this via code.? If I am adding ActionBar into LinearLayout, then we can add AdMob in any part (top,left,right,bottom) of the tab bar pages. How to achieve this.?